# How Do I Use the `directory` package?

Tags: bibtex, directory

I am completely unfamiliar with using the `directory` package, on top of which I do not understand how to use .bib files for this package. I cannot seem to duplicate the documentation's example, and it seems to me, as a novice user, that the documentation assumes a high level of understanding.

my `.bib` file looks like this:

```
% the name of this file is "home.bib"
@person{blah.doe
  name = "doe, blah",
  p.address = "642 blah dr.",
  p.city = "junkin",
  p.state = "MS",
  p.zip = "66554",
}
```

and my `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{directory}

\pagestyle{headings}
  \renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
   {\newpage\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
  {\item\hspace{-\dirindent}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\nodir{*}
  \directory{home}


\end{document}
```

Any help? I feel utterly lost. Also, the directory options are what are suggested in the `directory` documentation. This is as barebones as I can understand and manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the `.bib` file: a comma is missing at the end of the key. You're also missing a `\directorystyle` command.

In the example I use a `filecontents*` environment, just to keep the example self-contained; use your own file (and change `\directory{\jobname}` into `\directory{filename}`).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@person{blah.doe,
  name = "Doe, John",
  p.address = "642 blah dr.",
  p.city = "junkin",
  p.state = "MS",
  p.zip = "66554",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{directory}

\pagestyle{headings}
  \renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
   {\newpage\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
  {\item\hspace{-\dirindent}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\nodir{*}

\directorystyle{address}
\directory{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I was missing a few things; I had no idea. Thank you for your patience!